# Xamarin.iOS some items are not centered (X)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I try to put some items to page (Xamarin.iOS).

When I tested on simple page (ViewController) on iPad it looks like pretty.

[image]

But when I load the same UI logic via Wallet Extension (Modal page)

It looks bad.

[image]

Look at my code. Can you help to fix this issue? Maybe it related Simple page or Modal?

```
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        scrollView = new UIScrollView
        {
            Frame = View.Bounds,
            ContentSize = new CGSize(View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height),
        };
        View.AddSubview(scrollView);

        logoImageView = new UIImageView
        {
            Image = GetLogoImage(),
            ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit,
            Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(20, 100, View.Bounds.Width - 40, 150)
        };
        scrollView.AddSubview(logoImageView);

        titleLabel = new UILabel
        {
            Text = GetTitle(),
            TextColor = UIColor.Black,
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
            Frame = new CGRect(20, 220, View.Bounds.Width - 40, 30)
        };
        scrollView.AddSubview(titleLabel);

        descLabel = new UILabel
        {
            Text = GetDescription(),
            TextColor = UIColor.Black,
            Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize((nfloat)(UIFont.LabelFontSize * 0.75)),
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
            Frame = new CGRect(20, 250, View.Bounds.Width - 40, 30)
        };
        scrollView.AddSubview(descLabel);

        usernameField = new UITextField
        {
            Placeholder = "Username",
            BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect,
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(20, 350, View.Bounds.Width - 40, 35),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,    
            TextColor = UIColor.Gray,  
        };
        NSAttributedString usernamePlaceholderString = new NSAttributedString("Username", new UIStringAttributes { ForegroundColor = UIColor.Gray });
        usernameField.AttributedPlaceholder = usernamePlaceholderString;
        usernameField.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Gray.CGColor;
        scrollView.AddSubview(usernameField);

        passwordField = new UITextField
        {
            Placeholder = "Password",
            SecureTextEntry = true,
            BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect,
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(20, 400, View.Bounds.Width - 40, 35),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
            TextColor = UIColor.Gray,
        };
        NSAttributedString passwordPlaceholderString = new NSAttributedString("Password", new UIStringAttributes { ForegroundColor = UIColor.Gray });
        passwordField.AttributedPlaceholder = passwordPlaceholderString;
        passwordField.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Gray.CGColor;
        scrollView.AddSubview(passwordField);

        loadingSpinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Large)
        {
            Center = new CGPoint(View.Bounds.Width / 2, 480),
            HidesWhenStopped = true
        };

        scrollView.AddSubview(loadingSpinner);

        loginButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System)
        {
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect((View.Bounds.Width - 220) / 2, 520, 220, 45),
            // Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 2, 50),
            BackgroundColor = GetColor().ToUIColor(),
             
        };
        loginButton.SetTitle("Login", UIControlState.Normal);
        loginButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
        loginButton.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;
        loginButton.ClipsToBounds = true;
        loginButton.TouchUpInside += LoginButton_TouchUpInside;
        scrollView.AddSubview(loginButton);

        cancelButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System)
        {
            Frame = new CGRect((View.Bounds.Width - 220) / 2, 570, 220, 45),
            // Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 2, 50),
            BackgroundColor = GetColor().ToUIColor()
        };
        cancelButton.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;
        cancelButton.ClipsToBounds = true;
        cancelButton.SetTitle("Cancel", UIControlState.Normal);
        cancelButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
        cancelButton.TouchUpInside += CancelButtonTouchUpInside;
        scrollView.AddSubview(cancelButton);

        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, KeyboardWillShow);
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification, KeyboardWillHide);

        notificationLabel = new UILabel
        {
            TextColor = UIColor.Red,
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
            Alpha = 0,
            Frame = new CGRect(20, 620, View.Bounds.Width - 40, 30),
        };
        scrollView.AddSubview(notificationLabel);

        NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints(new[]
        {
            // Logo
            logoImageView.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(scrollView.CenterXAnchor),
            logoImageView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(scrollView.TopAnchor, View.Bounds.Height + this.keyboardHeight),

            // Title
            titleLabel.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(scrollView.CenterXAnchor),
            titleLabel.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(logoImageView.BottomAnchor, (nfloat)(View.Bounds.Height * 0.05)),

            // Description
            descLabel.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(scrollView.CenterXAnchor),
            descLabel.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(titleLabel.BottomAnchor, (nfloat)(View.Bounds.Height * 0.05)),

            // Username Field
            usernameField.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(scrollView.CenterXAnchor),
            usernameField.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(descLabel.BottomAnchor, (nfloat)(View.Bounds.Height * 0.05)),

            // Password Field
            passwordField.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(scrollView.CenterXAnchor),
            passwordField.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(usernameField.BottomAnchor, (nfloat)(View.Bounds.Height * 0.05)),

            // Login Button
            loginButton.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(scrollView.CenterXAnchor),
            loginButton.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(passwordField.BottomAnchor, (nfloat)(View.Bounds.Height * 0.05)),

            // Register Button
            cancelButton.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(scrollView.CenterXAnchor),
            cancelButton.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(loginButton.BottomAnchor, (nfloat)(View.Bounds.Height * 0.05)),
        });

        var usernameDelegate = new TextFieldDelegate(this, passwordField);
        usernameField.Delegate = usernameDelegate;

        passwordField.ShouldReturn = textField =>
        {
            textField.ResignFirstResponder(); 
            return true;
        };

        usernameField.EditingChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //descLabel.Alpha = string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernameField.Text) ? 1 : 0;
        };

    }
```

Can you help to fix this issue? Maybe it related Simple page or Modal?

Comment: That might be the issue in the ScrollView. It is recommended to make the ScrollView as the child layout in the Stacklayout or Gird.